# Lightweight alternative to GPX files to display Strava tracks in QGIS2Web map?

Tags: qgis

I have imported the track layer of hundreds of Strava GPX files into QGIS.

Now I have exported a web map with all these files as layers with QGIS2Web.

Because of the big data size everything is a bit slow.

Is there an alternative to using the GPX files which could improve the responsiveness?

I have also created a shapefile of the merged GPX files which loads faster but I would like to have the individual GPX files displayed in individual layers to turn them on and off.

Comment: How big a dataset are we talking? Have you tried simplifying the geometry to remove some vertices?

Comment: Also if it's just for visualisation purposes you could also strip some unnecessary attribute data.

Comment: We are talking about 300 gpx files.
I have already imported only the track layer from the Strava gpx files.
You can turn on the layers with the individual gpx files in the upper right in this example:
https://www.aronsommer.com/allstravaactivities/